# having problems updating yum on my centos 6.5 final system

Tags: yum, update

```
[root@spanky ~]# yum update
rpmdb: read: 0x7fff4032cbd0, 512: Input/output error
rpmdb: /var/lib/rpm/Providename: Input/output error
rpmdb: write: 0x12e1050, 4096: Bad file descriptor
error: cannot open Providename index using db3 - Bad file descriptor (9)
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

please can anyone help me?

Comment: Rpmdb is corrupt (try rebuilding) and looks like incorrect repo specs.

Comment: This looks like a defective disk. Any details in in the kernel log? You can see most recent messages with `dmesg` and older messages somewhere in `/var/log`

Comment: hi, i don't think the disk is defective as the server's just came up. how do I rebuild Rpmdb?

Comment: just tried to rebuild rpmdb and it's still not working.

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg | tail` ?

Comment: Dropped packet, source wrong from same IP

Comment: [root@spanky ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 1
'/bentOS-Base.repo\n'
seems this is now my error while updating yum

Comment: and now we're back
[root@spanky ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Comment: also, does this matter? 

[root@spanky ~]# rpm -q centos-release
package centos-release is not installed

Comment: Your rpmdb is beyond hope. If this is a virtual machine, abandon it and build a new one...probably at another provider. If it's a physical machine, have all of its hardware thoroughly tested.

Comment: actually i fixed this issue now I just read through some of the if anyone else is having issues please see this ---- repos need to change this mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=NAMEOFREPO to this mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
 as you can see I had to put the release as 6 and the arc as x64_86

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is well after the fact, but maybe someone else can benefit from the solution...

The solution for me was to update the value in the **/etc/yum/vars/releasever** file from 6.5 to just 6;

```
sudo echo "6" > /etc/yum/vars/releasever
```

this should actually be resolved to 6.6 by the mirrorlist server (at the time of this writing), or whatever happens to be the most current Centos 6.x release for which updates are available.